# Get text between two self-closing elements and number of following/preceding element

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

```
<text>
    <pb n="I"/>
    <p>
        <lb/>Lorem ipsum
        <lb/>Lorem ipsum
        <lb/>Lorem ipsum
        <pb n="II"/>
        <lb/>Lorem gipsum
        <lb/>Lorem gipsum
    </p>
    <p>
        <lb/>Lorem gipsum
        <lb/>Lorem gipsum
        <pb n="III"/>
        <lb/>Lorem hipsum
        <lb/>Lorem hipsum
        <lb/>Lorem hipsum
        <lb/>Lorem hipsum
    </p>
    <pb n="IV"/>
    <p>
        <lb/>Lorem dipsum
    </p>
</text>
```

From such a document, I am trying to get

1. all text and elements between two *pb* elements, when *@n* of the first *pb* is given,
2. and *@n* of the following and the preceding *pb/@n*, when *@n* of a *pb* is given.

Can anybody help? I am using XSLT 2.0 with SaxonCE.

EDIT: @ 2. the immediately following and immediately preceding.

Comment: Could you give an explicit output expected ? This will help to answer you rightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath 2.0 has operators `<<` and `>>` so your first question would translate into `//node()[. >> $pb1 and . << $pb2]` (within XSLT code you need to escape `<<` as `&lt;&lt;`, e.g. `//node()[. >> $pb1 and . &lt;&lt; $pb2]`). Selecting a `pb` element by its `@n` attribute should be obvious: `<xsl:variable name="pb1" select="//pb[@n = 'foo']"/>`. Defining a key `<xsl:key name="by-n" match="pb" use="@n"/>` with `<xsl:variable name="pb1" select="key('by-n', 'foo')"/>` might be more efficient.

Your second question might translate directly into an axis use: `$pb1/(preceding::pb | following::pb)/@n`. I am not sure however whether you want to find all preceding and following `pb` or only the immediately preceding respectively following ones.